# Ignoring certain url path, Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to disable all of the filters which Spring (or me) provide for the "/login" url. I've written this code, but Spring seems to ignore this lines of code. What am I doing wrong?

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors()
            .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().requestCache().disable()
            .logout().and().rememberMe().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/login");
}
```

Comment: Can you not just put in `.antMatchers("/login").permitAll().` before your other `.antMatchers()`?

Comment: Point 2 in this webpage: https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll . PermitAll doesn't turn off filters. It only turn off authentication

Comment: `web.ignoring()` is exactly how we do it and it completely bypasses spring-security that we set up on the `HttpSecurity` object just like we want it to. The only difference I can see is that we have (example) `/login/**` as an ant matcher rather than a fixed URI for the `web.ignoring()` call.

Comment: So I assume that a mistake must be somewhere else, because Filter is still being invoked

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where is your login form in httpSecurity, try something like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
                  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                  .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                  .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```